# echo output to be saved as param

Tags: batch-file

I have to pickup the latest file from the folder and do the further stuff in the database. So I was able to get the recent file from the folder as shown below

```
.os cd "C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\"
.os for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b *.*') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent% --GIVES THE RECENT FILENAME
```

I want to use the above output ie recent filename to below echo statement

```
echo .import vartext '  ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\'WANT OUTPUT OF ABOVE ECHO HERE' >>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
```

I tried the below script but not getting any

```
echo .Logon Teradata/username,password;>> C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
.os cd "C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\"
.os for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b *.*') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%
echo .import vartext '  ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\%recent%,skip=1;>>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
echo .REPEAT * >>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
```

---I am getting blank in the place of %recent%

Comment: You say in your original post that `echo %recent% ` gives the right output. Is this no longer true?

Comment: What is the prefix `.os` for??

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to echo the environment variable where you want it by enclosing it in percentage signs as you did before:

```
echo .import vartext '  ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\%recent%' >>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
```

---

Executing the following on my pc

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b .') do set recent=%%x 
echo .import vartext '  ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\%recent%'
```

Gives me

```
.import vartext '  ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\test4.bat '
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for your prompt reply I tried doing the same however I am not getting as below
.import vartext ' ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\,skip=1;--no name even after putting%recent%

Comment: if `echo %recent%` gives you what you want. Then the line I've shown will also give you what you want unless there's other stuff you are doing in-between. If there is then please post that.

Comment: I am using the below
echo .Logon Teradata.gdw.cba/username\password;>> C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
.os cd "C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\"
.os for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b *.*') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%


echo .import vartext ' ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\%recent%,skip=1; >>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
echo .REPEAT * >>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
echo  USING ( >> C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
echo  a varchar(500) >>C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt

Comment: @KrishNa Please don't paste code into comments, add it to your question and show what you get instead of what you expected

Comment: I want output in seperate file as in seperate file as 
.Logon Teradata.gdw.cba/username1,password;
.import vartext ' ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\OUTPUT OF ECHO,skip=1; 
.REPEAT * 
 USING ( 
 a varchar(500) 
) 
insert into UDRBSCMS.h_test 
values 
( 
:a );
.LOGFF; 
.QUITE; 
thanks for taking your time...

Comment: I've updated my answer with the output as tested on my pc and it's working fine. You're going to need to be a lot more clear if I'm going to assist you further. And add you requirements as an edit in your question, not as comments. Anywhere you wish to use the latest file just insert %recent%. It couldn't be easier.

Comment: I tried to post in question but it was bugging me to change the format...so now I have pasted in my script in original question itself....not sure why its not working for me....

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you aren't showing the important part of your batch-file, else the solution of @FloatingKiwi would work.

Perhaps your complete code is inside a block of parenthesis, than it could explain your result.

To avoid problems with percent expansion and blocks you can use delayed expansion, that also avoids problems with content like `)&` in your recent  filename. And at last I would build the output in a single block, so you need the file redirection only once.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\" 
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b .') do set "recent=%%x"
(
    echo .Logon Teradata.gdw.cba/username\password;
    echo .import vartext '  ' file = C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\!recent!,skip=1;
    echo .REPEAT *
    echo USING (
    echo a varchar(500^)
) >> C:\Users\krishha\Desktop\latest\h.txt
```

Comment: Hi Jeb, I was able to run the code given by you...thanks :) thanks again